# Handle key events when using Youtube iframe API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I was looking for a solution on how to handle key events when running Youtube videos on my application using Youtube iframe API. unfortunately couldn't find any. Did went through this documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events but it seems player doesn't fire any event related to key ( ex: onkeydown, keypress, keyup ).

I tried adding events directly to the provided code but it didnt worked.

```
 var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('trailer_video', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            // 'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
            'onkeydown': myfunction    // custom event 
          }
        });
      }
```

Is there any way I can handle key events specially when Arrow keys are pressed ?.

P.S: I dont know I might be wrong here but usually when i press Arrow keys while video is buffering, i see chain of dots moving which gives me a hint, that the player does detects these events and responds.

## UPDATE QUESTION

As answer below suggests which is ofcourse a solution in a way but since Youtube also handles left and right arrow key events its possible to use when cursor is over the video as well, My concern is, how can i handle the events for up and down arrow key which are not getting handled by Youtube and which only works when cursor is not over the video if I implement a custom event handler.

Comment: Can someone point me to some doc even. Youtube says their developers are here to answer every question related to this tag but doesn't seems correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. But the answer to your question, *"Is there any way I can handle key events specially when Arrow keys are pressed?"* is yes. Here is an example of a custom rewind/fast-forward functionality that uses the left and right arrow keys:

https://jsfiddle.net/xoewzhcy/3/

```
<div id="video"></div>

function embedYouTubeVideo() {
    player = new YT.Player('video', {
         videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
    });
}

function rewind() {
    var currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
    player.seekTo(currentTime - 30, true);
    player.playVideo();
}

function fastforward() {
    var currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
    player.seekTo(currentTime + 30, true);
    player.playVideo();  
}

$(function(){

    // embed the video
    embedYouTubeVideo();

    // bind events to the arrow keys
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        switch(e.which) {
            case 37: // left (rewind)
                rewind();
            break;
            case 39: // right (fast-forward)
                fastforward();
            break;
            default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
        }
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** Watch out for when you're focused on the embedded video (i.e., you click the YouTube play button or click into the YouTube iframe in any way). Because, your key events won't be listened to since the YouTube iframe is a completely separate window. To get around this, you could overlay a transparent div on the YouTube iframe and build your own play/pause buttons. That way no one can ever click into the iframe and lose focus of the parent window.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I know in a way it does solves the problem stated above but what if i really need to handle UP and Down arrow key event specifically?? cause what i can see is left and right arrows are getting handled by default from youtube but not up and down arrow keys.

Comment: If you wanted to use the up and down arrow keys, you could write functions for those then add an event to the switch statement.    `switch(e.which) {
            case 38: /* up arrow keycode */
                upfunction();
            break;
            case 40: /* down arrow key code */
                downfunction();
            break;
            default: return; 
        }` The keycodes refer to specific keys. Here is a link to mdn docs on the keycodes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: Yeah i did the same but the issue what i am facing here is, these events doesnt get handled when the cursor is over the youtube video.

Comment: Even the example you provided, its just working when click on the remaining space outside of video with 30sec + seek time and Also, by default youtube player handles left and right key events for forward and rewind but its not the same case for Up and down key as .

Comment: So, what I am looking trying to do here is how to add a custom event which will work even when the cursor is over the Video.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is an onKeyup or onKeydown event provided by the YouTube iframe api. I reviewed the events listed here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Adding_event_listener, and did not find anything of the sort. If I were you, I might try to overlay a transparent div atop the iframe so as to prevent a user from ever clicking in and losing the functionality of your custom listeners.

Comment: Yeah I went through this DOC already, but yes let me try this transparent div solution. thanks

Comment: Can anyone please post an example on how to overlay a transparent div and trap all keyboard (and ideally mouse) clicks events (stop propagation) so nothing goes to the YouTube player I made some attempts on a div wrapped around the <div id="player"></div> but youtube seems still to take over the moment it's clicked.
I am doing it from ionic/angular but I can interpolate from JS example.  thank you.